# How to get site name in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In the admin interface, I can see how I can specify the name of the site. But I can't find the documentation for how to use it in my templates.

Comment: Site is not a django cms feature, it is a Django feature:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem and found the solution answered in this post: [How to display the site's user friendly name in a template in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022280/how-to-display-the-sites-user-friendly-name-in-a-template-in-django)

Basically, in my settings.py, I had to add `'django.core.context_processors.request',` to my TEMPLATES -> OPTTIONS -> context_processors. Then you can access the site name in the template with `{{ request.site.name }}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set site name in **class requests.RequestSite**. It is a class that shares the primary interface of Site (i.e., it has a domain and name attributes) but gets its data from a Django HttpRequest object rather than from a database. You have to use **__init__(request)** in it to set the name and domain attributes to the value of get_host().

In *syndication framework*, templates for title and description automatically have access to a variable **{{ site }}**, which is the Site object representing the current site. Also, the hook for providing item URLs will use the domain from the current Site object if you don’t specify a fully-qualified domain.

In *authentication framework*, **django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView** passes the current Site name to the template as **{{ site_name }}**.

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/)