# How to display the site's user friendly name in a template in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I am searching for a way to display my Django-CMS site name in a template.

I created a basic Django-CMS site following [this guide](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/introduction/install.html). The default site is named Example.com and I was able to change this name, from within the admin section, to "My Super Site".
Following what, I tried to customize and apply a theme to it, following [this guide](https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2016/02/16/build-a-website-without-knowing-python-django-part-two/). It suggests to use `{{ request.site.name }}` to display the name of the site on a page. However this turns up empty and so does `{{ request.site }}`.

I searched further and found several pages approaching the subject with increasingly complicated propositions the older they were. Recent ones, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196940/how-to-get-site-name-in-django-cms-template), suggested that this was not related to django-cms but to django itself and the sites framework.

I looked into the documentation, particularly [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#attributes-set-by-middleware) and [this one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/#site-middleware) which, if I understood properly, indicates that the site middleware, once activated, includes a site object in the request object available in the templates. I checked and the sites framework is enabled ('django.contrib.sites' in INSTALLED_APPS setting, SITE_ID defined and migrate ran). So, I don't understand why `{{ request.site }}` is empty.

To clarify things, I am not looking for the domain name or the host. I am looking for the user friendly name, the one found in django-cms under 'Display Name' in the 'Change site' section of administration/sites.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

make sure to add `'django.core.context_processors.request'` to your context processors.

Like so:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Also add `django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware` to your `MIDDLEWARE` settings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Paulo. However this context processor is already in place.

Comment: @Xosted I've updated my answer to include the site middleware.

Comment: Well @Paulo that Sir, did the trick! At least the expected name seems to appear now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `django.core.context_processors.request` was moved to `django.template.context_processors.request` in Django 1.10.

Answer (score 1):

For newer version of django ie.. >3, only adding

```
'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware',
```

to the MIDDLEWARE in `settings.py` works. Then call

```
{{request.site.name}}
```

in your template.